# Spark SQL Broadcase Hint placement

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

I am trying to understand that if I use a small table alias multiple times (with diff where clause )  in my spark sql query , then I have to use broadcase hint multiple times OR just one time in any of the place .

Original query :

```
select   big_table.col_A,
dense_rank() over 
( order by big_table.col_B,
big_table.col_C,
nvl(small_table_aliasA.col_b,0),
nvl(small_table_aliasB.col_b,0) )  den_key_id,  
big_table.col_B,
big_table.col_C,
small_table_aliasA.col_b as aliasA_key, 
small_table_aliasB.col_b as aliasB_key
                         
                        from tableBig big_table
                                  LEFT JOIN
                                  (select  * from small_table where col_C = 'abc' ) small_table_aliasA
ON big_table.col_d = small_table_aliasA.col_d
                        
                                 LEFT JOIN
                                  (select  * from small_table where col_C = 'def'  ) small_table_aliasB
ON big_table.col_e = small_table_aliasB.col_d
```

**With Broadcast hint , should I use the hint each time I am referring the small table as below OR it should be just once **

```
    select   big_table.col_A,
    dense_rank() over 
    ( order by big_table.col_B,
    big_table.col_C,
    nvl(small_table_aliasA.col_a,0),
    nvl(small_table_aliasB.col_b,0) )  den_key_id,  
    big_table.col_B,
    big_table.col_C,
    small_table_aliasA.col_b as aliasA_key, 
    small_table_aliasB.col_b as aliasB_key
                             
                            from tableBig big_table
                                      LEFT JOIN
                                      (select /*+ BROADCAST(small_table ) */ * from small_table where col_C = 'abc' ) small_table_aliasA
    ON big_table.col_d = small_table_aliasA.col_d
                            
                                     LEFT JOIN
                                      (select /*+ BROADCAST(small_table ) */ * from small_table where col_C = 'def'  ) small_table_aliasB
    ON big_table.col_e = small_table_aliasB.col_d
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use broadcast everytime you need this hint

Here is small example:

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", False)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",100)

df1 = spark.range(1,10000).withColumnRenamed('id', 'new_column').cache()
df2 = spark.range(1,100000).withColumnRenamed('id', 'new_column_2')

df3 = df2.join(F.broadcast(df1),df2.new_column_2==df1.new_column,'inner')
df4 = df3.join(df1,df3.new_column==df1.new_column,'inner')
df4.show()
```

I disabled AQE and broadcast just to make it easier to reproduce this behaviour with small datasets.

Here is Physical plan for this query:

```
== Physical Plan ==
CollectLimit (17)
+- * Project (16)
   +- * SortMergeJoin Inner (15)
      :- Sort (10)
      :  +- Exchange (9)
      :     +- * BroadcastHashJoin Inner BuildRight (8)
      :        :- * Project (2)
      :        :  +- * Range (1)
      :        +- BroadcastExchange (7)
      :           +- InMemoryTableScan (3)
      :                 +- InMemoryRelation (4)
      :                       +- * Project (6)
      :                          +- * Range (5)
      +- Sort (14)
         +- Exchange (13)
            +- InMemoryTableScan (11)
                  +- InMemoryRelation (12)
                        +- * Project (6)
                           +- * Range (5)
```

It shows that when i added hint in first join, df1 was broadcasted but in next step it was not and sort merge join was executed

With hint in both join it looks like this:

```
df3 = df2.join(F.broadcast(df1),df2.new_column_2==df1.new_column,'inner')
df4 = df3.join(F.broadcast(df1),df3.new_column==df1.new_column,'inner')
df4.show()

== Physical Plan ==
CollectLimit (14)
+- * Project (13)
   +- * BroadcastHashJoin Inner BuildRight (12)
      :- * BroadcastHashJoin Inner BuildRight (8)
      :  :- * Project (2)
      :  :  +- * Range (1)
      :  +- BroadcastExchange (7)
      :     +- InMemoryTableScan (3)
      :           +- InMemoryRelation (4)
      :                 +- * Project (6)
      :                    +- * Range (5)
      +- BroadcastExchange (11)
         +- InMemoryTableScan (9)
               +- InMemoryRelation (10)
                     +- * Project (6)
                        +- * Range (5)
```

So no sort merge join but two BHJ

My conclusion is that you should use hint each time you are reffering your table

Answer (score 0):

If you use sql hint (such `/*+broadcast(small)`), then yes you will have to repeat the hint for each table alias you want to apply a given hint. Note that top hint won't apply in nested sql (see first example warning).

However if you use programmatic hint (`df.hint("broadcast")`), then every subsequent join to use it, and you won't have to repeat yourself. (see last example)

```scala
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "-1")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", "false")
spark.range(1,10000000).selectExpr("id", "id* 5 someval").registerTempTable("large")
spark.range(1,1000).selectExpr("id", "id * 2 val").registerTempTable("small")

// 1. one sql hint at top --> no broadcasts and a warning
spark.sql("""
select /*+broadcast(small) */ *
from large
left join (select * from small) small_1 using (id)
join (select * from small) small_1 using (id)
""").explain
// WARN HintErrorLogger: Count not find relation 'small' specified in hint 'broadcast(small)'.
// == Physical Plan ==
// *(8) Project [id#0L, someval#2L, val#29L, val#33L]
// +- *(8) SortMergeJoin [id#0L], [id#32L], Inner
//    :- *(5) Project [id#0L, someval#2L, val#29L]
//    :  +- *(5) SortMergeJoin [id#0L], [id#27L], LeftOuter
//    :     :- *(2) Sort [id#0L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
//    :     :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#0L, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#229]
//    :     :     +- *(1) Project [id#0L, (id#0L * 5) AS someval#2L]
//    :     :        +- *(1) Range (1, 10000000, step=1, splits=8)
//    :     +- *(4) Sort [id#27L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
//    :        +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#27L, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#235]
//    :           +- *(3) Project [id#27L, (id#27L * 2) AS val#29L]
//    :              +- *(3) Range (1, 1000, step=1, splits=8)
//    +- *(7) Sort [id#32L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
//       +- ReusedExchange [id#32L, val#33L], Exchange hashpartitioning(id#27L, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#235]


// 2. only one sql hint  --> one broadcast
spark.sql("""
select *
from large
left join (select/*+broadcast(small) */ * from small) small_1 using (id)
left join (select * from small) small_1 using (id)
""").explain
// == Physical Plan ==
// *(6) Project [id#0L, someval#2L, val#7L, val#11L]
// +- *(6) SortMergeJoin [id#0L], [id#10L], LeftOuter
//    :- *(3) Sort [id#0L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
//    :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#0L, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#62]
//    :     +- *(2) Project [id#0L, someval#2L, val#7L]
//    :        +- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [id#0L], [id#5L], LeftOuter, BuildRight, false
//    :           :- *(2) Project [id#0L, (id#0L * 5) AS someval#2L]
//    :           :  +- *(2) Range (1, 10000000, step=1, splits=8)
//    :           +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]),false), [id=#57]
//    :              +- *(1) Project [id#5L, (id#5L * 2) AS val#7L]
//    :                 +- *(1) Range (1, 100000, step=1, splits=8)
//    +- *(5) Sort [id#10L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
//       +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#10L, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#68]
//          +- *(4) Project [id#10L, (id#10L * 2) AS val#11L]
//             +- *(4) Range (1, 100000, step=1, splits=8)



// 3. two sql hint --> two broadcasts
spark.sql("""
select *
from large
left join (select/*+broadcast(small) */ * from small) small_1 using (id)
left join (select/*+broadcast(small) */ * from small) small_1 using (id)
""").explain
// == Physical Plan ==
// *(3) Project [id#0L, someval#2L, val#18L, val#22L]
// +- *(3) BroadcastHashJoin [id#0L], [id#21L], LeftOuter, BuildRight, false
//    :- *(3) Project [id#0L, someval#2L, val#18L]
//    :  +- *(3) BroadcastHashJoin [id#0L], [id#16L], LeftOuter, BuildRight, false
//    :     :- *(3) Project [id#0L, (id#0L * 5) AS someval#2L]
//    :     :  +- *(3) Range (1, 10000000, step=1, splits=8)
//    :     +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]),false), [id=#148]
//    :        +- *(1) Project [id#16L, (id#16L * 2) AS val#18L]
//    :           +- *(1) Range (1, 1000, step=1, splits=8)
//    +- ReusedExchange [id#21L, val#22L], BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]),false), [id=#148]



// 4. now one programmatic hint -> two broadcasts
spark.range(1,1000).selectExpr("id", "id * 2 val")
.hint("broadcast") // <--- look at that hint
.registerTempTable("small")
spark.sql("""
select *
from large
left join (select * from small) small_1 using (id)
join (select * from small) small_1 using (id)
""").explain
// == Physical Plan ==
// *(3) Project [id#0L, someval#2L, val#63L, val#67L]
// +- *(3) BroadcastHashJoin [id#0L], [id#66L], Inner, BuildRight, false
//    :- *(3) Project [id#0L, someval#2L, val#63L]
//    :  +- *(3) BroadcastHashJoin [id#0L], [id#61L], LeftOuter, BuildRight, false
//    :     :- *(3) Project [id#0L, (id#0L * 5) AS someval#2L]
//    :     :  +- *(3) Range (1, 10000000, step=1, splits=8)
//    :     +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]),false), [id=#610]
//    :        +- *(1) Project [id#61L, (id#61L * 2) AS val#63L]
//    :           +- *(1) Range (1, 1000, step=1, splits=8)
//    +- ReusedExchange [id#66L, val#67L], BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]),false), [id=#610]
```

Answer (score 0):

The hint should be placed after select, but you need to take into account that correct spacing is important so you need a space after `/*+` (see the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-hints.html)):

```
SELECT /*+ BROADCAST(<table>) */ * FROM <table> ....
```